# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to grab a webpage and load into a bootstrap 2.3.2 popover. So far I have:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "AjaxUpdate/getHtml",
  data: {
    u: 'http://stackoverflow.com'
  },
  dataType: 'html',
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
}).done(function(html) {
    console.log(' here is the html ' + html);

    $link = $('<a href="myreference.html" data-html="true" data-bind="popover"' 
            + ' data-content="' + html + '">');
    console.log('$link', $link);
    $(this).html($link);

    // Trigger the popover to open
    $link = $(this).find('a');
    $link.popover("show");
```

When I activate this code I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/q3vr5t00/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Good question.  Twitter bootstrap 2.3.x does not use fragments at all. Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle? Perhaps you are using some other library, trying to do something with the markup, like react.js or similar? Just theoretically.

Comment: Can you specify which line the error occurs on? A line number from your own code will be buried in the stack somewhere.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The reason for the error is the `$(this).html($link);`  in your `.done()` callback.

`this` in the callback refers to the `[...]object that represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to $.ajax)[...]` and not to the `$(".btn.btn-navbar")` (Or whatever you expect where it should refer to).

The error is thrown because jQuery will internally call `.createDocumentFragment()` on the `ownerDocument` of object you pass with `this` when you execute `$(this).html($link);` but in your code the `this` is not a DOMElement, and does not have a `ownerDocument`. Because of that `ownerDocument` is `undefined` and thats the reason why `createDocumentFragment` is called on `undefined`.

You either need to use the [`context`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  option for your `ajax` request. Or you need to save a *reference*  to the DOMElement you want to change in a variable that you can access in the callback.

Comment: Even though this may be a good answer, it does not explain the mysterious "_Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined_" error.

Comment: @davidkonrad edited the answer to add this information

Comment: It sounds plausible +1. Twitter bootstrap is heavily jQuery dependent. Good catch!

Comment: Thank you, could I ask a favour. I'm pretty inexperienced with js. I think I understand how to do the reference fix, but could I ask you to show me how to set the context property in this case using the fiddle as the basis?

Comment: @user61629 You just need to add the `context : theElementYouWant,` to your `$.ajax()` options (for more details you should look in the docs of [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that I have linked) and then the `this` in the callback will refer to the `theElementYouWant`.   I can't make an example as i don't know what element `this`  should be ;)

Comment: thanks @t.niese had the same issue. this worked `$.ajax({
   context: $(this),
   method: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: {leaveid_m: leaveid}
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
   $(this).text('loading...');
   $('#empdata').remove();
   var Summary_m = $(msg).find('#empdata');
   $('#empdata2').before(Summary_m);
  });`

Answer (score 14):

That error occur because `this` is referring to the ajax object and not on the DOM element, to solve this you can do something like this:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    var thisForm = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'www.example.com',
        data: {}
    }).done(function(result){
        var _html = '<p class="message">' + result + '</p>';
        $(thisForm).find('#resultDiv').html(_html);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That error occurs because this usually refers to the ajax object and not on the DOM element, to prevent this assign this in a variable like below:

```
/* To add add-on-test in cart */
$(document).on("click", ".aish_test", function(){
          var thisButton = this; //Like this assign variable to this
          var array_coming = '<?php echo json_encode($order_summary_array);?>'; //Json Encoding array intersect variable
          //Converting in array
          var array_check = $.parseJSON(array_coming);
          var result = [];

            for(var i in array_check){
                result.push(array_check [i]);
            }

          //Fetching data:
          var test_data_name = $(this).attr("data-name");
          var test_data_price = $(this).attr("data-price");
          var test_data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        
         if($.inArray(test_data_id, result) == -1)
            { 
            //static html 
            var static_html = '<tr><td>'+test_data_name+'</td>';
            static_html += '<td>&#163;'+test_data_price+'</td>';
            static_html += '<td><button type="button" class="close remove_add_test" data-id="'+test_data_id+'" data-price="'+test_data_price+'" aria-hidden="true"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </button></td></tr>'; 
               /*ajax call*/
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'scripts/ajax/index.php',
                        data: {
                            method: 'addtocart',
                            id: test_data_id,
                            name: test_data_name,
                            price: test_data_price
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data.RESULT == 0) {
                                $(thisButton).text("added to cart"); //Use again like this
                                $(".cart-number").text(data.productcount);
                                $.growl.notice({
                                    title: "Shopping Cart",
                                    message: data.MSG
                                });
                            $('#myTable tr:first-child').after(static_html);
                            } else if (data.RESULT == 2) {
                                $.growl.error({
                                    title: "Shopping Cart",
                                    message: data.MSG
                                });
                            } else {
                                $.growl.error({
                                    title: "Shopping Cart",
                                    message: data.MSG
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
            }
            else
            {
                $.growl.error({
                                    title: "Shopping Cart",
                                    message: "Already in Cart"
                                });
            }
            
    });
```