# How to get html into a bootstrap 2.3.2 popover, dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button where I would like to create a bootstrap popover containing html dynamically when I hover over it. So far I have:

```
$(".btn.btn-navbar").hover(function() {
  html = '<ul class="nav"><li><a href="#">hola</li><li><a href="#">hola2</li></ul>';
  $link = $('<a href="myreference.html" class="p1" data-html="true" data-bind="popover"' 
          + ' data-content="' + html + '">');

  console.log('$link', $link);
  $(this).html($link);

  // Trigger the popover to open
  $link = $(this).find('a');
  $link.popover("show");
}, function() {
  console.log('$hi there ');
});
```

<kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/ct616j5n/1/)</kbd>

I'm having trouble getting the html into the popover properly.
Can someone give me a hand with this.

Comment: As this question is related to you previous one you should mention that [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177917). And you should really correct the indenting of your code using some tidy tool.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your help on the last problem. The last problem was solved. This is a related problem which I've come across, but I've tried to simplify the question and make it stand on its own. I've tidied up the code as you suggested. - Bill

Comment: But you still should always link your prev question if it is a follow up, this will make it easier for others to actually understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual problem here is `' data-content="' + html + '">'`

You should do the concatenating your self to see what is happening.
The result of it would be:

```
<a href="myreference.html" class="p1" data-html="true" data-bind="popover" data-content="<ul class="nav"><li><a href="#">hola</li><li><a href="#">hola2</li></ul>">
```

The problem is at this part:

```
data-content="<ul class="nav"><li>
```

The `data-content` attribute will only contain `<ul class=`, additionally your `<a>` tag will end here  `data-content="<ul class="nav">`

To correctly add the `html` to the `data-content` you should do it this way:

```
html = '<ul class="nav"><li><a href="#">hola</li><li><a href="#">hola2</li></ul>';
$link = $('<a href="myreference.html" class="p1" data-html="true" data-bind="popover">');
$link.data('content', html);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need to create a link dynamically with popover or you need to create popover with html inside only. I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ct616j5n/3/) showing how to create popover dynamically with custom html inside.

```
function createHoverPopover(htmlContent, jqueryElement, direction) {
jqueryElement.popover({
    html: true,
    placement: direction,
    trigger: "hover",
    content: htmlContent,
    selector: true
}); }
```

Comment: I really like this solution ! What I would need to do is combine it with the code in http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/q3vr5t00/2/  because ultimately the html will be rturned from a server via ajax

Comment: you can call ajax and when it successfully returns the html, call the function above in ```.done(function() { });``` pass in the HTML content to htmlContent :). (I suggest to use GET instead of POST)

Comment: something like this 
`$(".btn.nav-btn").hover(function() { //call ajax .done(function(html) {createHoverPopover(html, $(this), "bottom");});});`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the string concatenation, I would create the html element like

```
html = '<ul class="nav"><li><a href="#">hola</li><li><a href="#">hola2</li></ul>';
$link = $('<a />', {
    href: 'myreference.html',
    "data-html": 'true',
    "data-bind": 'popover',
    "data-content": html
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3nk57f4c/)