# Preloader not getting dismissed on timeout, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Strange issue with my website: the page loads normally when tested on local machine but after deployment the preloader (visible only on desktop) doesn't get dismissed.

The template that I'm editing uses jQuery 3.2.1

```
jQuery(window).load('body', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.mihi_tm_preloader').addClass('loaded');
    }, 1000);
});
```

---

### Update:

**1.** After checking out, on my local machine it throws those errors in console:[image: local machine error]

**2.** When deployed to server it gives those errors:
[image: server error]

Comment: Check the network activities in developers console and make sure there is nothing stuck in loading level

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
    at qa (jquery.js:3)
    at Ja (jquery.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.append (jquery.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3)
    at T (jquery.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.html (jquery.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.js:4)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at A (jquery.js:4)`

Comment: Also I suggest using $(window).on("load",function(){}) instead if you are using latest version of jquery

Comment: The problem is that the template came with this version of jQuery ..you can check in the source at js/init.js, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was with the **`jQuery(window).load('body', function()`** so i removed it and added a simple delay function:

```
function dismiss_preloader(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.mihi_tm_preloader').addClass('loaded');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of  undefined" which is causing your jquery not to be executed.

Here's a link to help you figure out where your issue is or maybe post your jquery for more help.

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177917/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-createdocumentfragment-of-undefined)

Comment: Can't figure out where fragment is used

Comment: If you post your jquery maybe a new set of eyes will help

Comment: May I ask where you got the 'container' variable in container.find() in your progress bar function? Otherwise I didn't really see anything glaringly obvious